# not getting image src in my BeautifulSoup csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am getting image src in my python shell look like this:

```
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41oJQTxCbZL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4152DCmmGFL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ayV4UraXL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/310z8LQ%2BoYL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif
```

But I am getting image src in my csv file look like this:

```
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif"/>
```

**Product title**, **product price** and **product rating** importing in my csv file exactly look like my output of python shell but not getting image src in my csv file look like python shell. Here is an example of my  final output which I am getting from python shell:

```
product_link: https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_btf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A002532917E3JT34GS1DE&url=%2FWireless-Vssoplor-Portable-Computer-Computer-Black%2Fdp%2FB07RLYJJBX%2Fref%3Dsr_1_22_sspa%3Fcrid%3D22TI4BA3RLK5J%26dchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dwireless%2Bmouse%26qid%3D1599517835%26sprefix%3Dw%252Caps%252C528%26sr%3D8-22-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1600050591&id=4126203954910776&widgetName=sp_btf

product_title: Wireless Mouse, Vssoplor 2.4G Slim Portable Computer Mice with Nano Receiver for Notebook, PC, Laptop, Computer-Black and Sapphire Blue

product_price:  $10.99 

product_rating: 2,262 ratings


image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41oJQTxCbZL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4152DCmmGFL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ayV4UraXL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/310z8LQ%2BoYL._AC_US40_.jpg
image link:https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif
```

**here is my full code:**

```
for page_num in range(1):
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wireless+mouse&page={}&crid=22TI4BA3RLK5J&qid=1599517835&sprefix=w%2Caps%2C528&ref=sr_pg_2".format(page_num)
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers,proxies=proxies,auth=auth).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')

    container = soup.find_all('h2',{'class':'a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2'})
    for containers in container:
        product_link = f"https://www.amazon.com{containers.find('a')['href']}"
        print(f"page_number:{url}\n\nproduct_link:{product_link}")

        #here I am start scraping from details page of each product 
        details_page = requests.get(product_link,headers=headers,proxies=proxies,auth=auth).text
        dpsoup = BeautifulSoup(details_page,'lxml')

        
        title = dpsoup.find('span', id='productTitle')
        if title is not None:
          title = title.text.strip()
        else:
           title= None
        rating = dpsoup.find('span', id='acrCustomerReviewText')
        if rating is not None:
           rating = rating.text
        else:
           rating = None
        price = dpsoup.find('span', class_='a-size-mini twisterSwatchPrice')
        if price is not None:
           price = price.text
        else:
           price = None
        print(f'\nproduct_link: {product_link}\n\nproduct_title: {title}\n\nproduct_price: {price}\n\nproduct_rating: {rating}\n\n')

        #this is for scrape all gallray image src
        for url in dpsoup.select('span.a-button-text > img')[3:10]:
         print(f"image link:{url['src']}")

        
        with io.open("amazon.csv", "a",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writeFile = csv.writer(f)
            writeFile.writerow([url,product_link ,title,rating,price])
```

**note:** for every product I am getting multiple image url in my python shell but only one image url importing in my csv file

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are writing the CSV row **outside** the loop for the image urls. Change to something like:

```
for url in dpsoup.select('span.a-button-text > img')[3:10]:
    print(f"image link:{url['src']}")
    writeFile.writerow([url, product_link, title, rating, price])
```

Comment: hi jcragun it's not working..getting getting multiple image url in my python shell but only one image url importing in my csv file

Comment: @boyenec even after making the change suggested above? Only other thing is you may need to use `url['src']` instead of `url`.